# why it is printing [object] as alert

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    user name:
    <input type="text" id="t1">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">display</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var str;
            str = document.getElementById("t1");
            alert(str);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above program it is displaying [object] inside the alert box,I don't know why,I want to display what ever user input in the text box.help me..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only getting the html element which is represented as an object, not the actual contents of the `<input>`. You need to explicitly get that content using `.value`:

```
   function myFunction() {
        var str;
        str = document.getElementById("t1").value;
        alert(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
str = document.getElementById("t1")
```

to:

```
str = document.getElementById("t1").value;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zQaRF/)**

`document.getElementById("t1")` refers to the element so you need to specify the property of the element you want. In this case, the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` variable contains a reference to the object itself, not the text inside. What you want is:

```
str = document.getElementById('t1').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `t1.value` in the alert. `t1` is the whole input element but you are only interested at what has been entered i.e. its **value**.

Answer (score -3):

rather than `alert(str)`, use `console.log(str)`, then check browsers console

Comment: While logging to console might be helpful for inspecting `str`, his problem is that `str` is `#t1`, not `#t1`'s value.